# mxKeyHandler not working when React component is remounted

Tags: reactjs, single-page-application, mxgraph

I'm using **mxGraph** in a **React Single Page Application** and instantiating a new **mxKeyHandler** in **componentDidMount**. I also invoke its **destroy** method in **componentWillUnmount**. It all works fine the first time you visit the page that has the **mxGraph** component, but if I navigate away to a different page and come back (without a page refresh), it no longer works.

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.editor = new mxEditor();
    this.editor.setGraphContainer(this.mxGraphRef.current);
    ...... 
    this.keyHandler = new mxKeyHandler(this.editor.graph);
    this.keyHandler.bindKey(46, evt => {
      this.editor.graph.removeCells();
    });
}

componentWillUnmount() {
    this.keyHandler.destroy();
    this.editor.destroy();
}
```

Any advice as to what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, the solution was to add the following 2 lines:

```
this.editor.graph.container.setAttribute('tabindex', '-1');
this.editor.graph.container.focus();
```

As described here: https://jgraph.github.io/mxgraph/docs/known-issues.html#Focus